# Java Bean contents

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller

I referred to Java MVC, and I understood the following.(please correct me if I'm wrong)

```
M->Model(It is a Java Bean)
V->View(JSP/HTML)
C->Controller(Servlet)
```

1. Here when going through Java Beans in JDBC there are getters and setters, I want to know if this is all the columns from my DB, for example, I've 10 Columns, Do I need to do a Getters and Setters for all the 10 Columns?
2. Should I write my JDBC code in `Servlet` or `Bean`?
3. In my JSP I've two textboxes that fetch data from Database Columns. for that I use to do something like below (Just for Demonstration sake).

`

```
<table>
     <tr>
         <td>
             <input type="text" value="<%=i%>" name="id1" id="id1">
         </td>
         <td>
             <center>
                 <input type="text" value="<%=rs.getString("DBID")%>" readonly="readonly" id="abc<%=i%>" name="abc<%=i%>" size="100">
             </center>
         </td>
         <td>
             <input type="text" value="<%=i%>" name="id2" id="id2">
         </td>
         <td>
             <center>
                 <input type="text" value="<%=rs.getString("description")%>" readonly="readonly" id="ab<%=i%>" name="ab<%=i%>" size="100">
             </center>
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

`

Here I'm fetching content from database and putting it in 2 textboxes.

How can I do it using MVC approach?

Answer (score 0):

> > 1.Here when going through Java Beans in JDBC there are getters and setters, I want to know if this is all the columns from my DB, for example, I've 10 Columns, Do I need to do a Getters and Setters for all the 10 Columns?

Yes you need 10 properties with the getter and setter.

> > 2.Should I write my JDBC code in Servlet or Bean?

The JDBC code should be in a service which is called from the controller or in the controller itself.

> > 3.In my JSP I've two textboxes that fetch data from Database Columns. for that i use to do something like below(Just for Demonstration sake).

You have to call the getter of the bean for the property you need.

You can find good [tutorials](http://www.javatpoint.com/MVC-in-jsp) in the web.

Answer (score 0):

Please do more study to understand for e.g. http://howtodoinjava.com/2015/02/05/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/

But i ll try to answer ur questions

1) Here when going through Java Beans in JDBC there are getters and setters, I want to know if this is all the columns from my DB, for example, I've 10 Columns, Do I need to do a Getters and Setters for all the 10 Columns?

-> A Java bean need not have "all" the columns, instead bean should reflect truly which fields (whether columns in DB tables or computed ones) are required at the "view" (or calling business logic).

2) Should I write my JDBC code in Servlet or Bean?

-> JDBC code can be put into a separate LAYER - read more about DAO and layered architectures.  So a single controller class receives an event (request) and then call the appropriate "manager" class which know what bunisess action is requried. It can call other manager classes which intern can call DB layer (DAO will help here)

for e.g. suppose controller receives request to create Order  -->
Controller.invoke(Request reqCreateOrder) --> CreateOrderHandler.execute(OrderBean ob) ---> OrderDao.create(OrderVO) ---> [insert query]

3) In my JSP I've two textboxes that fetch data from Database Columns. for that i use to do something like below(Just for Demonstration sake).

--> similarly for fetch as well

Controller.invoke(Request reqFetchOrder) 
--> FetchOrderHandler.execute(OrderBean bean) ---> OrderDao.fetch(OrderBean bean) ---> [select query]
--> FetchOrderView.render(OrderVO bean) --> invokes JSP !!

Answer (score 0):

MVC is just a paradygm. In real world you may have much more layers :

- view (JSP) (the less possible scriptlet here)
- front-controller (provided by a framework such as Spring MVC or Struts)
- controller (provided by programmer) : processes request parameters, call next layer and forwards to a view
- service : implementation of business rules <= here should be the intelligence
- persistence (JDBC will come here, but you could have ORM such as Hibernate or JPA)

Object model (beans) go through all those layers.

It would be too long for a SO answer to explain all that so :

- search on google and wikipedia for MVC and MVC2 patterns
- read tutorials (Struts, Spring, Hibernate ...)
- discuss with fellows that already used them => not to be done in SO
- choose an architecture with or without framework (*)
- try it and than ask precise question here if needed

(*) Even without framework try to separate view (JSP) - controller (servlet) - service - persistence